# Straight or linear helix

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, terminology

If a helix is discontinued for a short while and then continues in a different direction, I prefer to call in "kinked". If the helix is simply uniformly following one direction, I prefer to call it "straight", but I have corrected, and been told that it is called "linear". Which is right?

Thank you!

[image: Kinked and straight helix]

Comment: Welcome to ELL.SE. In layman usage, *straight* is perfectly reasonable to describe the lower helix, so if you have been "corrected" by someone, you are writing in some specialized domain which has its own argot, and you would be best to consult authorities within that realm. It might be one thing in molecular chemistry, another in paper craft, yet another in topology, or it just may be known by a certain term within your lab or firm.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because, as choster says, this use is *jargon* and should conform to the most commonly used adjective in that field, to avoid confusion.  It has little to do with general-use English.

Comment: You can choose to call it whatever you wish. Moreover, in terms of other people understanding you, nobody would misunderstand the use of *straight*.